# Resize Image to fit page based on height

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I'm having an issue. I have a square image (2048x2048) that I want to use as a background. I want it so that when a page is stretched into a widescreen aspect ratio there will be borders on the page. I also want it so that when the width of the page is made smaller than the aspect ratio, the image resizes to maintain it's square shape.

It seems that I can only do one of these, not both.

If I use: `height:100%` as a CSS property on the image, it works for larger screen sizes, but when the screen is made smaller, the image does not resize to fit and I get horizontal scroll bars.

If, on the other hand I use:`width:100%;`as a CSS property, it works great for small screens, but once it's resized to fit the full screen, I get vertical scroll bars...

I thought that if I were to use:

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

or

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```

that it would work, but apparently not...

I've also tried giving the `body`tag `max-height:100%`, and even a container div the same property, but no luck...

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: did you use `background:cover;`

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either. Am I supposed to use it in conjunction with other tags? I've tried width and height at 100%

Comment: can you create a fiddle so that i can help you ?

Comment: Give me a few minutes

Comment: My code is here [link]https://jsfiddle.net/q3Lwo6ta/[/link]

Comment: the link is showing 404 status

Comment: Try the one in the comment below

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the `body` the background and specify `background-size` with a value of `cover`?

```
body {
  background: url("2048x2048.png");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

From the docs, about [`cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

> A keyword that is the inverse of contain. Scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom. The image is automatically centered unless over-ridden by another property such as background-position.

Comment: Ok, actually I think I misphrased my original post. It's supposed to be an *overlay* to a background... sorry. So there will be a background image that spans the full page and then this will overlay a square in the center. Do the same things apply?

Comment: @user3910071 Yes, it does apply. Try it out. If there's a fiddle, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what You are trying to achieve?

https://jsfiddle.net/z9mc0g4t/

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://thefoxisblack.com/desktop-wallpaper/Slumber-wallpaper-ipad.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Not really, because I always want to see the full image, meaning that I'll want side borders so that it maintains it's square aspect ratio

Comment: you mean you want to see a website scrollbars, when the browser height is too small? Because in this example you get the full image with proper aspect ratio.

Comment: I don't want any scrollbars. I always want the website to resize the image so that there are no scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
body {
background-image: url('imageurl.png');
background-size: contain;
}
```

@user3910071 you can do for `img` elements also with this piece of CSS -

```
img {
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

See here a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wupsyuga/1/), resize the Result window and see if the image resizes as per your need.

Comment: contain gets me closer, but what if it wasn't going to be used as a background image? what if I want to use the image as an overlay to the background?

Comment: @user3910071 if you can create a proper working example on jsfiddle then I can think about it. Also if it is not a background-image then try this - `max-height: 100vh; max-width: 100vh;`

Comment: @user3910071 have you checked my updated answer?? see the fiddle demo I've provided in my answer and please reply it works as expected or not? see this - http://jsfiddle.net/wupsyuga/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
background-size: cover;
or 
background-size: contain;

Comment: contain gets me closer, but what if it wasn't going to be used as a background image? what if I want to use the image as an overlay to the background?

Comment: you can try: background-size: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

You want your image width-height should follow to your window width-height always with true aspect ratio and without no white-space anytime?

if i understand correctly to you try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bqra/uhsy2ro7/)

```
$(function() {

// responsive wallpaper
var img = $('.big_backgrounds img');
function bigPic() {
    if ( img.width() < $(window).width() ) {
        $('.big_backgrounds img').css({
            'width': '100%', 
            'height':'auto', 
            'left':'0', 
            'margin-left':'0'
        });
    } else if ( 
        img.outerHeight() > $(window).outerHeight() ) {
        img.css({
            'width': '100%', 
            'height':'auto', 
            'left':'0', 
            'margin-left':'0'});
    } else {
        img.css({
            'width': 'auto', 
            'height':'100%', 
            'left':'50%', 
            'margin-left': -(img.width()/2) });
    }
} 
bigPic();
$(window).resize(function () { 
    bigPic() 
});

});
```